# Sketching objects near each other

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics

I want to sketch the below graph on the screen:

```
             |----|    sphere
             |----|
             / /
            / /
           / /         cylinder
          / /
         / / angle = 45
         | |
         | |
         | |           cylinder
         | |
         | |
         | |
 -----------           cylinder
 -----------
```

My output:

```
             / /
            / /
           / /         cylinder
          / /                        |-----|  sphere
         / / angle = 45              |-----|
```

I will sketch the top part namely sphere with a cylinder. My code is below, please look and say what is wrong.

I have tried to find the error why my primitives do not near to each other. But, I could not find. I have tried to change parameters of translate, but it does not work. Please, help

```
void object(void) {
    GLUquadraticObj *t = gluNewQuadratic();

    glTranslatef(-2.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    gluCylinder(t, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.3f, 32,32);
    gluSphere(t, 0.2f, 26, 13);

}

void display(void) {
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();
    object();
    glPopMAtrix();
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();        
}

void reshape(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0f, w/h, 1.0, 500.0f);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate in between the calls to gluCylinder and gluSphere. In the current code, they will both have the same transformations, i.e. they will be in the same position/orientation. Try:

```
gluCylinder ( t, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.3f, 32,32);
glTranslatef ( -2.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f );
gluSphere ( t, 0.2f, 26, 13 ) ;
```

Also you call PopMatrix() more times than you call PushMatrix().

Comment: Have you compiled the code with your point ? I have done and it does not work.

Comment: Nope, Rearranging those three lines shouldn't prevent the code from compiling. If the original code compiled then my changes shouldn't make any difference

Comment: No, I know it can be compiled, I mean have you run the code

Comment: Sorry, my bad, no I haven't compiled it. I thought this might give you a quick fix. Try removing the LoadIdentity() in reshape after you call gluPerspective. In display() you should also set matrix mode to model view before applying any transformations

Comment: I know you may be busy. But, forgive me, Can you give whole coed with fix ?

Comment: Sorry man, I'm not going to do your assignment for you.

Comment: @Slicedpan: Well, I just did, and added some animation as well: http://imgur.com/fCgGg – giving out the code? Assignments are given out to learn.