# sketch cylinder

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sketching object near to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518651/sketching-object-near-to-each-other)

I want to sketch below graph in the screen ;

```
             |----|   sphere
             |----|
             / /
            / /
           / /         cylinder
          / /
         / / angle = 45
         | |
         | |
         | |           cylinder (i)
         | |
         | |
         | |
 -----------           cylinder
 -----------
```

To sketch the cylinder marked with (i), I have use below code, can you help me what is my mistake because I could not manage to draw (i) ?

```
glTranslatef(0.0f, 10.0f, 400.0f ) ;
glColor3f ( 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) ;
glRotatef (90.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
gluCylinder(quadric,0.0f,200.0f,100.0f,32,32);
glTranslatef(0.0f, 10.0f, -400.0f ) ;
```

Comment: You asked this before. And it wasn't a real question then, and it isn't one now.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't try so hard to solve this particular problem, but approach the more basic steps first: Setting up a window and context, viewports, projection, modelview and transformations.

Comment: but these two are different questions

Comment: Also your mistake is probably, that you just Copy'n'Pasted some random code together, without a clear understanding, what it actually does. This "Cargo Cult Programming", never gets you far, and you should not even attempt to hand that in, because some TAs tend to give negative points on that (when I was TA I did give negative points, whenever I encountered a Cargo Cult Program).

Comment: @user1845897: No they're not different in their quality; you're still stuck on understanding transformations, and how the matrix stack works. This is homework, apparently, and I really urge you, to grab some book (maybe online) and *understand* what you're actually doing. It was very easy for me, to write down a solution for you, but you wouldn't learn anything from it.

Comment: @datenwolf all your words are worth diamonds. (Yup, been in the TA chair too once...)

Comment: why just do you show mistake with explanation ?

Comment: @user1845897: To make you stop trying to cheat, and actually learn, what you're supposed to learn. You may think I'm getting snarky at you, but actually I want you to pass that class. But for that you must *understand* what you do. Just showing you some code won't help; you'd not be the wiser after reading that either.

Comment: I'd suggest the same, as datenwolf did: generally, if you are stuck with something, step back a bit from the code, and imagine what you want to achieve. **In this case of 3D problem** close your eyes, and assemble the scene in your head. Step by step. Imagine the cylinder. What is its **orientation**? Is it correct? If not, you have to rotate it. Is the **position** correct now? If not, you have to "push it" to the right place. Find the appropriate matrices for each step, and do this for each and every part. The first will be tough. The second will not be easy, but the third will go fine!

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to be the bad guy here, so let me explain, why that bit of code is worth nothing without the context and why you need to understand.

Let's go through this snippet line by line. It all starts with

```
glTranslatef(0.0f, 10.0f, 400.0f ) ;
```

The first question is: What matrix is this operating on. Probably modelview, but we don't know. And what is the matrix before that call to glTranslatef? OpenGL matrix operations somewhat like x86 assembly, in that they replace the matrix on the stack with the result of the operation.

```
glColor3f ( 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) ;
```

This set the color state. Of course. One normally groups this call with the geometry to be drawn, and not put it somewhere in the middle of the code though.

```
glRotatef (90.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
```

Rotating about the axis (1, 1, 0), i.e. it's like sticking a axle through the object, passing through the local origin and going toward the point (1, 1, 0), and then rotating this by 90° about this axis.

```
gluCylinder(quadric,0.0f,200.0f,100.0f,32,32);
```

Now a cylinder is drawn, which will be first rotated, then translated, and then… only you know, because you omitted the part, where the modelview matrix is reset when beginning rendering the frame.

```
glTranslatef(0.0f, 10.0f, -400.0f ) ;
```

And the final glTranslatef does not have any effect on drawing the cylinder whatsoever.

---

You see the problem now? You're asking a very specific question, that's clearly homework, put some piece of random code in there, just ask "how to draw it" without any idea, what you're actually doing.

There's no way we can help you, if you don't first grip the basics first. We'll gladly help to get you there. Start with drawing something simple, like a triangle centered in the window.